# MFC and SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database, mfc, sql-server-express

I have following code to get information from edit control and write into the database.

There is problem with connection string and driver. I tried to use tools>connecting database but it didn't work, and also there is interesting problem that I can read from database but I can't write.

Are there any suggestions for string connection, or am I doing it the wrong way?

```
CString  Name, Surname;
m_name.GetWindowTextW(Name);
m_surname.GetWindowTextW(Surname);  
CStringA temp1(Name);
CStringA temp2(Surname);    
const char* pstrName = ((const char *)temp1);
const char* pstrSurname = ((const char*)temp2);
CDatabase database;
CString SqlString;
CString sDriver = _T("SQL Server");
CString sDsn, sMc;
CString sFile = _T("C:\\Users\\Emaaad\\Name.mdf");
sDsn.Format(_T("DRIVER=SQL Native Client;SERVER=.\SQLExpress;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Initial Catalog=ADOTest"), sDriver, sMc, sFile);
try
{
    database.Open(NULL, false, false, sDsn);
    CRecordset recset(&database);
    SqlString = _T("insert into Categories(CatID, Category) values(");
    SqlString.Append(Name);
    SqlString.Append(_T(","));      
    SqlString.Append(Surname);
    SqlString.Append(_T(")"));
    CStringA temp3(SqlString);
    const char* pstrSql = ((const char *)temp3);
    database.ExecuteSQL(SqlString);
    database.Close();
}
catch (CDBException* e)
{
    AfxMessageBox(e->m_strError);
}
```

Comment: *"it didn't work"* is not an error description. How does it fail, and which one? Your code has so many commented out lines, that it's pretty much impossible to see, what you are trying. Unrelated to your issue (whatever that is), you are leaking an exception object. Unless you are re-throwing `e`, you have to invoke `e->Delete();` on it (see [Exception Handling in MFC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t078xe4f.aspx)).

Comment: yes maybe but the main problem is the connection.

Answer (score 0):

If "Name" and "Surname" are to be stored into char/varchar/nvarchar columns they should be in single quotes ... maybe that's the problem with the insert statement you generate ...

Comment: thanks for answer . but i have problem with connection to send data from vs2015 to ms sql

Answer (score 0):

You have instantiated a CRecordset but are not using it. SQL is fine for quick and dirty but as you want to do more complicated things it can be hard to manage. Even using CRecordset directly can be restrictive. Derive from CRecordset, like:

header:

```
class MyRecordset : public CRecordset
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(MyRecordset )
public:
    MyRecordset ( CDatabase* pDatabase );
    void Open( );
    //you may have specialized stuff, optional
    void OpenOrdered( LPCTSTR lpszSQLCoulomb );

    long ds_id;
    CDBString ds_name;
    long ds_ordered;

public:
    virtual void DoFieldExchange( CFieldExchange* pFX );
};
```

cpp:

```
void RaCatRecordset::DoFieldExchange( CFieldExchange* pFX )
{
    pFX->SetFieldType( CFieldExchange::outputColumn );
    DBFX_Long( pFX, _T("CategoryKey"), ds_id );
    DBFX_Text( pFX, _T("Name"), ds_name );
    DBFX_Long( pFX, _T("Ordered"), ds_ordered );
}
void RaCatRecordset::Open( )
{
    VERIFY( CRecordset::Open( CRecordset::dynaset, _T("[Categories]") ) );
}
```

Now you can use the CRecorset methods  to manage your records. If you change the record structure you won't have a bunch of SQL to maintain. You can add, edit, delete, set bookmarks, iterate, find... And with very simple SQL words if at all.

ADDED: It occurred to me there is something important about the constructor. You will want to set m_nFields, the number of DoFieldExchage calls, or it will fail.

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC( RaCatRecordset, CRecordset )
RaCatRecordset::RaCatRecordset( CDatabase* pdb )
    :CRecordset( pdb )
    ,ds_id( 0 )
    ,ds_ordered( 0 )
{
    m_nDefaultType= dynaset;
    m_nFields= 3;
}
```

Comment: but another question how can i copy the string from edit control to the table

Comment: and another question . when i want to write query to add another column it says you are not connected to the database

Comment: If you use the record set directly you would Edit( ), set the value of the members, then Update( ). Look over the documents on CRecordset. If you have a form view it can be derived from CRecordView. Microsoft has an example project that does all the stuff. You should download it and start there. It should be very rare to create columns programmatically, usually you start with a database that you've created with a database app. As for 'easier way', I have no idea what your objectives are.

Comment: its not about adding columns it is just taking name and surname ... from edit control ( user input) and paste it into database (row)